# How to update data from same data every night?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I Have my table like this:

[image]

What i want  is how can i update amount from each ID everynight. For example Today date is 8 - 5 - 18 and if goes to 9 - 5 - 18 , i want like to update wallet date to be 9 - 5 - 18  date and amount should be previous date amount. Thanks.

```
ID      Amount      Wallet Date 
1        1000      8 - 5 - 18
```

After Next Date

```
ID   Amount  Wallet Date
1    1000    9 - 5 - 18
```

Comment: Use cronjob its a best and comman way to do this

Comment: @RavindraBhanderi I know for that . But i want to know query for updating . Thanks.

Comment: opps its not describe currently so its a simple update current date and time in the cron job or add one day into current walletDate

Comment: you need to select first all record from database and then process into foreach

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in root directory say *updateDateCron.php*

Put bellow code into into *updateDateCron.php*

```
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "yourDB";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET wallet_date = $current_date";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
   ?>
```

Set cornjob using bellow steps which runs every day at midnight

1. Run `cronjob -e` into command line.
2. Add line `00 00 * * * path/to/your/updateDateCron.php`

Cron runs everyday at midnight and your `wallet_date` will updated.

Answer (score -2):

Write below code in cronjob.php:
mysql_query("update TABLE set  Wallet_Date =Wallet_Date+1");

set cornjob: 01 01 * * * /opt/lampp/bin/curl http://host/web_service/cronjob.php

Comment: How should i set for the amount also and i want to update for every id.

Comment: Your requirement is "amount should be previous date amount" . So, no need to update amount field.

Comment: Curious why not execute the PHP file directly, why use curl ?

Comment: you can also use php instead of curl:  opt/lampp/bin/php http://host/web_service/cronjob.php  or direct sql comand /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -ppass dbname< /opt/cronjob.sql